# Стрелка на чистом css

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать такую стрелку на css.высота стрелки 10px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `::before`, `::after` и `border` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: а как бордер правильно использовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте 2 бордера и `transform:rotate(45deg);`

```css
.arrow {
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px; 
  background-color: #f61;
}

.arrow:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-right: solid #fffa;
  border-top: solid #fffa;
  width: 7px;  /* sqrt(7*7 + 7*7) */ 
  height: 7px; /* это примерно 10 */
  transform: translate(8px, 10px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Comment: подскажите пж как его позиционировать теперь

Comment: он у меня в другом блоке и я хочу ему сделать падинг справа но стрелка деформируется

Comment: если покажете - исправлю

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте новый код:

css >

```
img {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

html>

```
  <img src="..." style="width: 10px; height: 10px;" alt="...">
  <img src="..." width="10" height="10" alt="...">
```